# Drawing images to canvas with objects

Tags: javascript, html, oop, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to create a game with objects. I'm trying to draw my Link object to the canvas, but it won't work for some reason. I've tried methods described in other answers for this question. I don't understand why the image won't display on the canvas! Here is my code (edited to the relevant bits).

HTML

```
    <script src='animateLink.js'></script>
    <script>
    //canvas variables
        var canvas, ctx;

    //key control variables
        document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler);
        document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler);
        var leftKey, upKey, rightKey, downKey;

        leftKey=false;
        upKey=false;
        rightKey=false;
        downKey=false;

    //Link variables
        var link = new Link('../image_files/link_left.png',200,200,19,27,0);

    //main animation functions
    function initialize() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('hello');
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        update();
    }

    function update() {
        if(leftKey && link.linkX>0) {
            link.linkX--;
            link.frameX++;
            link.src='../image_files/link_left.png';
        }
        else if(upKey && link.linkY<0) {
            link.linkY--;
            link.frameX++;
            link.src='../image_files/link_up.png';
        }
        else if(rightKey && (link.linkX+link.frameW)>canvas.width) {
            link.linkX++;
            link.frameX++;
            link.src='../image_files/link_right.png';
        }
        else if(downKey) { //probably won't use
            link.linkY++;
            link.frameX++;
            link.src='../image_files/link_down2.png';
        }

        if(link.frameX>15) {
            link.frameX=0;
        }

        draw();
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }

    function draw() {
        clearRect();
        link.sketch();
    }

    document.write(link.toString());


    function clearRect() {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    }

    //control functions
    function keyDownHandler(e) { //SET TO BOOLEAN VALUES NOT STRINGS
            switch(e.keyCode) {
                case 37: leftKey=true; break;
                case 38: upKey=true; break;
                case 39: rightKey=true; break;
                case 40: downKey=true; break;
            }
        }
    function keyUpHandler(e) {
        switch(e.keyCode) {
            case 37: leftKey=false; break;
            case 38: upKey=false; break;
            case 39: rightKey=false; break;
            case 40: downKey=false; break;
        }
    }
</script>
<body onload='initialize()'>
    <canvas id='hello' width='1424px' height='810px'></canvas>
</body>
```

JS

```
//animated objects
    //use frameW/H/X
function Link(src, linkX, linkY, frameW, frameH, frameX) {
    //this.x=x?x:10;
    //src entry will equal path to image file

    this.src=src?src:'../image_files/link_left.png';
    this.linkX=linkX;
    this.linkY=linkY;
    this.frameW=frameW;
    this.frameH=frameH;
    this.frameX=frameX;
}

Link.prototype.toString = function() {
    return("("+this.src+","+this.linkX+","+this.linkY+","+this.frameW+","+this.frameH+","+this.frameX+")");
};

Link.prototype.sketch = function(ctx) { //(ctx)
    var img = new Image();
    /*img.onload = function() {
        //ctx.drawImage(img, this.linkX, this.linkY, this.frameW, this.frameH);
        ctx.drawImage(img, //image
            display.linkX, //frameX
            display.linkY, //frameY
            display.frameW, //frameW
            display.frameH, //frameH
            display.linkX, //imageX
            display.linkY, //imageY
            display.frameW, //imageW
            display.frameH); //imageH
        }*/
    img.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(img,this.linkX, this.linkY, this.linkW, this.linkH); 
    };
    img.src = this.src;

};
```

Comment: Have you checked your console for error messages? [Open up your developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and tell us if you see any errors.

Comment: The console says it "cannot read property 'drawImage' of undefined" at line 34 (context.drawImage(img,this.linkX, this.linkY, this.linkW, this.linkH);). I realized I accidentally wrote context instead of ctx, but I still don't know how to correctly reference the canvas. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: To access the canvas, you can do `var canvas = document.getElementById('hello')`. That works because you gave your canvas an ID of "hello". To get the context, you can do `var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')`. I highly recommend going through [MDNs material on working with the canvas.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial) It's where I learned almost everything as it pertains to the canvas.

Comment: That code is in my HTML. What I really meant was why doesn't it work to write "cxt.drawImage(img,this.linkX, this.linkY, this.frameW, this.frameH);" when I've defined what ctx is. Sorry for being unclear!

Comment: I figured out the issue! When I called sketch in my HTML, I wasn't entering ctx as a parameter. Thank you so much!!